Why was this question downvoted and who downvoted it?
Why was this question downvoted and who downvoted it? I don't understand the reason of downvoting this question. And I can't read the name of the user who downvoted (too small reputation score I think). Can anybody help?
Question

The rules are that users who have accumulated enough reputation are trusted to be judicious with voting.  No user is obliged to explain their upvotes nor downvotes to any author. Hundreds of users have complained about this system, hundreds of requests have been posted on Stack Exchange Meta and Stack Overflow meta, and nothing has ever changed.  The whole Stack Exchange model is based on the concept that good posts receive upvotes, while defective posts (and answers too) will receive downvotes to ensure quality is met. You are not obliged to like this system but it is what it is.

See: Encouraging people to explain downvotes and What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?

Read the Help section, do the tour and discover yourself the facts. The only time downvotes are reversed is when someone abuses the system, when they downvote a series of posts belonging to one author. That is called serial downvoting. Do some research on Meta, and good luck if you find any member of staff supporting justifying downvotes, or forcing users to accompany a DV with a comment. Do you have to explain yourself when you vote for a candidate in an election? You're doing this all the wrong way. If you had asked how to fix or improve a post, the response would have been more helpful.

Read this request and the answers: See who is upvoting/ downvoting my question/answer

It's anonymous, no one knows why someone chooses to DV a post unless they post an accompanying comment. Nobody knows. The voting is anonymous. As a hi-rep user I can see users' voting patterns, i.e how many upvotes vs downvotes but I don't see which posts they voted on. For example, on EL&U I see you have not cast any downvotes but you have cast 18 upvotes on 18 answers, two of which were cast this month. But I don't see which answers you upvoted. End of.

I'm not interested at all in who downvoted any question Erm... in your question you clearly state … and who downvoted it? … and … And I can't read the name of the user who downvoted … If you've since changed your mind I would call that progress.

"The whole Stack Exchange model is based on the concept that good posts receive upvotes, while defective posts (and answers too) will receive downvotes to ensure quality is met." - That is the point, actually! What is a good post, what is a defective post? The downvoters have to decide! And when you have to decide you need a gauge, a benchmark! And what is the benchmark on this site? That's easy to answer:  It is the rules the questioners have to obey! That means even though the downvoting is anonymous or for this very reason the downvoters have to comply with the rules.

And when the downvoting doesn't comply with the rules the downvoters make a mistake!

Are you still upset? It's the community that cast their votes, everyone has their individual parameter. For example, if I see an unattributed source for the tenth time by the same user, despite solicitations,  my mouse twitches towards the down arrow. I've had plenty of downvotes, some were inexplicable, a few I could get behind, so I tried to improve my post, but even so I still get the occasional DV, years after I posted an answer. Eventually, when you build enough rep the DVs will stop being annoying and you'll shrug them off. Certainly not worth losing a night's sleep. Time to move on.

The way voting works here is not very different from the way it works in a typical election in a democratic society. Just like in the world at large, the voters are expected to exercise their right to vote responsibly and to have good reasons for voting one way rather than another, so they are here, and you are right to expect that. But, just like it is a feature of voting in the world at large that voters cannot be made to explicate their reasons and enter into debates about them, so it is here. This is not some bizarre peculiarity of this site, as you keep treating it.

By design, voting is always anonymous around here. You do not gain the ability to see how someone voted by accumulating more reputation.

If so, will those who make a wrong decision be called to account by anyone?

@philphil That is not how things work here. People are allowed to vote however they please based on content.  Unless the system automatically detects and reverses a flurry of votes from one user to another, being indicative of disallowed personal bias not mere content assessment, there is nothing  than can, will, or should be done. Related: 1, 2, 3, et cetera.

See also the position of one of the founders and creators of our voting system here: “The whole point of voting is that it is egalitarian and anonymous, just like in a democratic political election.”

There is nothing egalitarian or democratic in this approach or management at all. The questioner is fair game there - that's all! In a democracy there is an election every few years,. There the administration/government is called to account, isn't it? So, how is a downvoter called to account on this site?

As an aside, do you know why this question was downvotwd? Does it comply with the rules?

Ms Bunting has already given you the most likely explanation of why the question was downvoted, its obviousness, which arguably could be  a reason for closing it as well. There seems to emerge a pattern in which you ask why something has happened, and when you are given an explanation of how it is in accordance with the norms of this site, it turns out that what you really want is to argue that the norms ought to be changed.

And I don't habitually criticize the rules. tchrist has addressed the discussion of the downvoting practise there https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75966/proposal-to-solve-the-uncommented-downvote-problem/76028#76028 and what I said is my response to it, nothing else.

My question is: Do you know why this question was justifiably downvoted ? Does this downvoting comply with the rules?

No voting (up or down) needs to be justified at all. It's completely anonymous† and there is no-one to call to account. Consequently all downvoting complies with the rules: the downvoter thought the post deserved it. That's the way SE works: if you don't like it, you'll need to ask on [meta.se] but do note that there have been loads of similar questions in the past and you'll simply be downvoted and have your question closed. [† Staff on SE do have access to voting records, but they are only accessed when rules have been broken.]

@Andrew Leach - "Staff on SE do have access to voting records, but they are only accessed when rules have been broken." - I don't understand that. What do you mean by "have access to voting records"?

@philphil Voting records are maintained so that the system can undo votes cast by a user who is removed, or where voting fraud is found. While most of that is handled automatically, staff do have access to users' votes.

"No voting (up or down) needs to be justified at all. . . , and there is no-one to call to account. Consequently all downvoting complies with the rules." - Everyone has to stick to the rules on this site, even the downvoters:  The rules justify the downvoting. And: The downvoting has to comply with the rules. If the downvoting doesn't follow the rules the downvoting doesn't comply with the rules. Consequently there isn't any "all downvoting complies with the rule". My question was downvoted. And the downvoting has to comply with the rules: . . .

You yourself are saying "all downvoting complies with the rules". Consequently there has to be a sound, substantiated reason for downvoting my question that complies with the rules. Please tell me this reason (this is my original question here and it hasn't been answered up to now).

@philphil Do NOT clutter the comments here with questions that should be asked on the main site; I have deleted all of that spam you just now inappropriately wrote here. //  And you have been given your answer here, so you won't be getting any others: nobody has to "justify" anything about their anonymous voting on Stack Exchange.


I haven't been given my answer here, actually. It is Not obvious a non-native speaker is able to know the phrase **strip the table bare" has a figurative meaning as well. How is a non-native speaker supposed to know that this phrase has the meaning 'the others will have scoffed the food before you have located your cutlery' as well? If there is no evidence or proof in the dictionaries or internet this question complies with the rules. 2) Of course, nobody has to justify anything about their anonymous voting because it is anonymous.


However their downvoting has to comply with the rules - that's the point.  If their downvoting doesn't comply with the rules they have made a mistake.

@philphil No, you are wrong. Enough already. Nobody has to justify their votes. Period and end of discussion.  Stop pestering about this point because you will never get anywhere given that you are wrong. If you don't like it, go post to [meta.se]. We've told you this before and we won't tell you again.
